# Como enviar sms usando javascript ou angular ou node.js Gratuitamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic

Bom dia, necessito de um método ou api que envie sms gratuitamente, pode ser do meu numero mesmo da tim(tenho plano de sms), procurei e apenas achei algumas pagas de fácil uso... estou me preparando para um hackathon da universidade e preciso de produzir isso para ter um diferencial no produto final.
o app será em angularjs, ionic e as apis em nodejs. Existe alguma maneira de fazer?

Comment: Você pode usar um model 3G com um Chip que tenha credito para fazer os envios.

Comment: Você esta usando iis ou apache? Ou a sua página é somente html css e js?

Comment: como funciona o model 3g?

Comment: ainda não foi definido o servidor, provavelmente o iis... a page usa html, angularjs, javascript, css, podemos adicionar jquey caso necessário